# div position in an another div

Tags: html, css

i'm desperatly trying to understand how divs work in HTML. here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="user_p">
    <img src="img/pp/djbaptou.jpg">
    <div class="followings"> djbaptou </br> Baptiste Arnaud </br> Description : Salut j'aime les carottes lol
        <a href="#">Modifier profil</a>
    </div>
    <div class="followings"> Suivi de : </br> 200 </br> personnes</div>
    <div class="followings"> Suivi par : </br> 300 </br> personnes</div>
</div>
```

and here is my stylesheet related to this part of HTML :

```
#user_p{
    background-color: red;
    width: 60%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}

#user_p img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.followings{
    font-family: "Roboto-Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Can you explain to me how the hell can it be displayed like this :

[image: capture]

I want my green divs to be centered

And also, if i resize my window it looks like this:

[image]

I just want the green divs to stay in the red one ...

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Use media queries to make the divs smaller.  If the div is narrower than 600px (3*200px) they won't fit. What else were you expecting?

Comment: Try using the padding-top property to adjust suitable padding for the green divs to center vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be vertically centered, you could use flexbox and make `#user_p` a flex container with the `display: flex;` property and give it `align-items: center` for vertical alignment. Additionally, you can get rid of the `inline-block` display values of child elements. Also, if you want something that's truly responsive and looks good at different sizes, I'd recommend using media queries and adjusting the `flex-direction` value to `column` on smaller screens and `row` on bigger ones, and playing around with other flexbox properties.

```
#user_p{
    background-color: red;
    width: 60%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}

#user_p img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.followings{
    font-family: "Roboto-Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank you very much my friend ! :D

Answer (score 1):

this my first answer ever so i hope it will help you 
this is how i changed the style sheet so it will serve your purpose

```
        #user_p {
        background-color: red;
        display:inline-block;
        padding-right:100px;
        margin: auto;
    }

        #user_p img {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

    .followings {
        font-family: "Roboto-Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        width: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: green;
        margin-left: 60px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

first thing, your main div should be set to *display:inline-block;* , witch basically means it's width will auto adjust as you put elements in to it, and since your green divs are set to *display:inline-block;* the red div will autoscale automatically in width, so you have to **disable it's width property** and since it scales to the minimum it can, put padding right to ofset the most right green div of yours

**Use media queries?** This is what i learned from my HTML experience, if you make the website correctly, even when you scale it to the bear minimum it won't be as pretty as with media queries but everything will be absolutely visible.

Comment: It doesn't work here, i'm trying to vertically center the green divs in the red divs

Comment: ye but you said  'Can you explain to me how the hell can it be displayed like this :' and i made it look like this, you didn't said anything about vertical alight :) i will show this as well in a min